# CentOS7.2.1511でキャッシュからのyumインストールパッケージを使うには

Tags: centos, yum

CentOS7.2.1511を使っています。
過去に一台のPC(PC A:7.2.1511)ではyumで必要なパッケージをインストールしました。・・・(A)
最近、新たにもう一台のPC(PC B:7.2.1511)でyumインストールを試みたところ、
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.2.1511/
のレポジトリのファイルはすでになくなっていました。

しかし、PC Aの/var/cache/yumにはyumでインストールしたパッケージのファイルがキャッシュされているようで、これを使って、PC Bでも同様のパッケージをインストールしたいと思いました。

質問1: /var/cache/yumのキャッシュはPC Bにコピーしてyumインストールできるものなのでしょうか？
質問2: 可能ならばどのようにすればできるのでしょうか？参考になるURLでも構いませんのでご教授お願いできればと思います。

何卒よろしくお願いします。

＃ パッケージの関係でOSはバージョンアップしたくありません。その前提です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/yum.conf で `keepcache=1` と設定されていれば `cachedir` で指定したディレクトリに RPM ファイルが残ります。RPMファイルを 別サーバーにコピーしてから、 rpm コマンド、または yum コマンドで インストールやアップデートが可能です。

ただ、過去にキャッシュをクリアしていればその分は消えてます。また依存関係のあるパッケージも含まれているかどうかは 分かりません。

古いバージョンのリポジトリは http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/ にあるので そこから yum でインストール/更新するほうが 無難な 印象です。

(Readmeから引用)

> If you know what you are doing, and absolutely want to remain at the 7.2.1511
>   level, go to http://vault.centos.org/ for packages.

/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo  の `mirrorlist` と `baseurl` の行をコメントアウトして`baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/$basearch/` を追加すれば yum で 参照出来ると思います。

CentOS-Base.repo の例

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&>infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Comment: 以前似たような回答をしたのでリンクしておきます: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/47547/2808

Answer (score 2):

`var/chache/yum`にrpmパッケージ(rpmファイル)が残っており、かつ対象のパッケージに依存関係が無ければ該当のファイルを別のPCにコピーして`rpm`コマンドでインストールすればよいでしょう。

```
# rpm -ivh PACKAGE.rpm
```

もしくは過去のパッケージを公開している http://vault.centos.org というサイトがあるので、`yum`の参照先を一時的にでも書き換えてこちらからインストールする方法もあります。

CentOS 7.2.1511 (x86_64)のパッケージディレクトリ
http://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/updates/x86_64/Packages/

参考：
[yum updateできなくなった古いCentOSでyumコマンドを復活させる方法](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tmatsuu/20120324/1332578375)