# CentOS7.4.1708のyumレポジトリの内容が消えていた場合

Tags: centos, yum

CentOS7.4.1708を使っています（このバージョンにあわせたアプリケーションがあり、バージョンがあげられません）

`/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` では下記のURLを見にいく設定になっていますが、

```
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
```

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/ 配下のファイルが消えています。

他サイトを参考にして mirror.centos.org の部分を vault.centos.org に書き換えると、このサイトにはファイルはあるのですが、yumで無いものもあるようです。
ftp.riken.jp は mirror.centos.org と同じように削除されています。

どのように解決すればいいか、ご存知の方ご教示お願いします。

(追記)
ローカルレポジトリを作成して試しました。以下のアプリケーションが無い模様。インストールCDでもないものなのでしょうか。

```
Error downloading packages:
   systemtap-runtime-3.2-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   gcc-c++-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   redhat-rpm-config-9.1.0-80.el7.centos.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   libstdc++-devel-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   systemtap-client-3.2-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   rpm-libs-4.11.3-32.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   rpm-4.11.3-32.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   rpm-sign-4.11.3-32.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   libgfortran-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   gcc-gfortran-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   libstdc++-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   rpm-build-4.11.3-32.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   elfutils-libs-0.170-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   libquadmath-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   libquadmath-devel-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   systemtap-3.2-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   elfutils-0.170-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   cpp-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   subversion-libs-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   systemtap-devel-3.2-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try. 
   rpm-python-4.11.3-32.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   rpm-build-libs-4.11.3-32.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   libgcc-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   libgomp-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   gcc-4.8.5-28.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   elfutils-libelf-0.170-4.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

yum groupinstall failed!
```

Comment: 古いバージョンを参照して何がしたいのでしょうか。代替案としてはインストールメディアを用意してローカルリポジトリを作成する方法も考えられます。

Comment: この代替案で実施したいです。インストールメディアは用意（マウント）できます。具体的に、CentOS-Base.repoをどう書き換えたらいいかなど、参考になるURLなどありましたらご教授お願いしたくよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/yum.repos.d/` ディレクトリに CentOS7.4-Vault用の.repoファイル(ファイル名例:`CentOS7.4-Vault.repo`)を新規作成し、次の内容を書き込みます。同ディレクトリにある `CentOS-Vault.repo`をコピーしたのち編集するのが楽かもしれません。

```
[C7.4.1708-base]
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - Base
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[C7.4.1708-updates]
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - Updates
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[C7.4.1708-extras]
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - Extras
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[C7.4.1708-centosplus]
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

[C7.4.1708-fasttrack]
name=CentOS-7.4.1708 - CentOSPlus
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/fasttrack/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1
```

後は、`yum`コマンド実行時の引数として `--disablerepo=* --enablerepo=C7.4.1708-*`を付与するようにしてください。
例:

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=C7.4.1708-* check-update
```

どのリポジトリのファイルを取得しようとしているかは、`yum`コマンド実行時の出力で確認できます。

[image: yum実行確認]

常にこの参照リポジトリ設定を有効化する場合は、 `yum-utils`をインストールすることで使用可能になるコマンド`yum-config-manager`で、

```
sudo yum-config-manager --disable "*"
sudo yum-config-manager --enable "C7.4.1708-*"
```

としてください。

---

質問文中に書かれているようなエラーになっているのは http://vault.centos.org/centos/7/ を参照するような設定になっているためでしょう。
(歴史的経緯は知らないのですが、これは7.5リリース向けに準備しかかったファイルを含むリポジトリではないでしょうか)

Answer (score 0):

7.4.1708のインストールメディアが用意できるのであれば、ローカルにyumリポジトリを作成してそちらからパッケージをインストールする方法もあります。

ISOイメージをマウント
(DVDの中身をローカルにコピー、または直接参照)
yumリポジトリの設定ファイルを作成
作成したリポジトリを参照してyumを実行

という流れになります。

参考
https://server-setting.info/centos/yum-install-from-dvd.html

Comment: 試してみましたが、無いアプリケーションがある模様です。

Comment: 具体的なパッケージ名を挙げてもらった方が回答も具体的にできると思います。

Comment: 質問文に追記させていただきました（パッケージ名）

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` をテキストエディタで開いて、`mirrorlist` の行をコメントアウトして、`baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.4.1708/os/x86_64/` を追加します。

`yum clean all` キャッシュ等を削除して、`yum install xxx` すれば 古いパッケージを インストール出来ないでしょうか？